# Limit map visibility to its overlay

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to place an image over my map and limit the map visibility to the image overlay, so that the user can only see my image and not the map behind it. I tried to used the solution offered by Google Maps API with the GMSGroundOverlay, like so:

```
let southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.712216, longitude: 32.22655)
let northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.773941, longitude: 23.12544)
let overlayBounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: southWest, coordinate: northEast)

let icon = UIImage(named: “someImg”)

let overlay = GMSGroundOverlay(bounds: overlayBounds, icon: icon)
overlay.bearing = 0
overlay.map = mapView
```

Also, I set the cameraTarget of the map to the bounding box:

```
mapView.cameraTargetBounds = overlayBounds
```

This does limit the user from scrolling the map infinitely, but I expected  these limits to go as far as the overlay goes. Now the image looks like a sticker on the map, as I can still see the map around the image.

I am not sure I fully understand the way GMSCoordinateBounds and GMSGroundOverlay work..so I'm asking here if anyone can give me some hints on the adjustments that I can make to get what I want.